# Enable OpenGL on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm running Trisquel Mini 6.0.1, which is based on the repos for Ubuntu 12.04 on a netbook. I have a lightweight game that I'm trying to run written for the `love` interpreter, but it fails to initialize.

```
$ love mygame.love
Could not set video mode: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
Error: [string "boot.lua"]:286: Could not set screen mode
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    [string "boot.lua"]:286: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:221>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

The first line is the meat of the problem, obviously. Here's the info about my card:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -A2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011]
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:041a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

What packages might I be missing which are required to enable OpenGL rendering for such a card?

Answer (score 0):

Post the output from

```
lspci -knn | grep -A2 VGA
```

Go [there](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/) for latest linux drivers

However the fact that you got a match with grep means a driver is already used. Use the above command to find out which.

Comment: Changed the lspci output